# Where is OOS LogLocation path for Win2019?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, log, oos

We have a SP2019 farm. OOS is deployed and configured in the same domain with Windows Server 2019. The installation seems success but none of the SharePoint document load up. It always returned an error `Something went wrong and we couldn't load this content. Refreshing the browser may fix the problem` with the Session ID. I need the log to further troubleshoot it.

According to some articles the default log path is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS`. Also we verified with PowerShell `(get-OfficeWebAppsFarm).loglocation` which returned the same path. However in the OOS server we don't have `C:\ProgramData\`. I don't think we have changed the path because we are running install with default value.

What should I do? Is Win 2019 not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. C:\ProgramData is hidden by default. By enable the showing of "Hidden items" I am able to open the log path.